# Javascript custom object with a constant variable, and what to do when object scales with many functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps this is a really simple question but I'm having trouble finding it online. I have years of basic Javascript experience - I'm a bit ancient to all the modern JS libraries so I am now trying to catch up :) I need to add some functions (I am free to make any changes that I want to improve things for scalability) to the following Javascript object.

```
var MyCustomObject = {

    myNum: 12345,

    foo: function() {
         console.log(myStaticNum);
    }

    // and some more functions exist here {removed for this post}
}
```

I first want to start by having some constant for `myNum` - how would I do that in Javascript? I can't seem to use `const` here or perhaps I need to place it correctly somewhere to make the number constant, just for the purpose of semantics (it doesn't currently affect my web app if it is a `const` or not - I'm just curious if it can be used).

Further to this, this custom object is used by other places in an existing app (kind of a basic skeleton) and I am want to add several modular and related functions into it to build my app. While this makes sense if I had 5-10 small functions, what happens as I grow my app and I keep adding functions into this space?

For example, what if I soon will have 20 functions in there, and then 100 eventually? Please point me to any recommended reading references. I'm reading through: https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices and this is very useful, but I'd like how to make the above object scalable or whether it is advised that I simply divide the object into sub-objects (i.e. `vars` within the `var` if possible).

Also from my (basic) understanding from [reading articles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) online so far, is the above OOP? (I suspect that it is.)

Comment: Well, it's not at all clear what you're actually trying to do here. Why is `myNum` a property of the object instead of a module-level (or even global, since it isn't changing) constant? Why do you have methods on your object that are pure functions and could easily just *be* functions? Are you trying to use an object as a namespace? Does this thing need to encapsulate some state with an API for manipulating it?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. This is an assignment that I have - and the skeleton is pre-built for me, and this particular object is a "Utils" object (by name) to hold functions that will interact with an API - essentially the meat of my app. `myNum` is just a variable I defined in there to hold an ID I need for the API. I probably need to define more. The object (by skeleton) should contain the API interaction code. I would then need to update the DOM with some status messages and HTML, and I'm not sure if I should do that in the object or somewhere else.

Comment: Just make it a top-level constant `const myNum = 1234`.

Comment: Terms I am unfamiliar with in your question: "module-level" constant, and "use an object as a namespace" - I'll look these up now

Comment: In JavaScript modules (they're relatively new) top level declarations don't leak into the global scope the way they used to. As for the using an object as a namespace, this used to be a common pattern in JS for libraries. Consider underscore: all the library functions are bound to `_` like `_.chain`. All the `_` is doing is acting as a namespace to group that functionality. I would *guess* that's what the skeleton you were given is doing, especially with a name like 'utils'.

Comment: Thank you @JaredSmith ! I think so too. Would you recommend adding as many functions as I want to this namespace, as long as they belong there? I need to deal with error handling and results from the API (to write to the DOM) - would you say that this object/namespace hold all of those functions as well? e.g. I need to use the Facebook API to log in. If they are not logged in, I need to print a message on DOM to say so and print the login button.